# What code is better to use for operator overloading

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, operator-keyword

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Overload operators as member function or non-member (friend) function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1905439/overload-operators-as-member-function-or-non-member-friend-function)

In process of learning operator overloading in C++ I have seen two different types of overloading operator +.

I need your help to tell me which method is better to use:
Method first:

```
Complex Complex::operator + (Complex &obj) {
   return Complex( re + obj.re, im + obj.im );
}
```

Method second:

```
Complex operator + (const Complex &obj1, const Complex &obj2) { 
    // this function is friend of class complex
    return Complex(obj1.re + obj2.re, obj1.im + obj2.im);
}
```

Thank you!!!

Comment: Does [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1145022/220636) or [that](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8509046/220636) help?

Comment: @TonyDelroy thanks I did not notice it before

Comment: @depecheSoul Please don't mark questions answered by adding 'solved' in the tile. Accept the best answer. Have a look at the FAQ to get used to StackOverflow and enjoy your time here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As long as there can be no implicit conversions, both are equally good;
it's more a matter of taste.  If there can implicit conversions to
`Complex` (which in this case seems likely), then with the first form,
implicit conversions will only work on the second argument, e.g.:

```
Complex c;
Complex d;

d = c + 1.0;    //  Works in both cases...
d = 1.0 + c;    //  Only works if operator+ is free function
```

In such cases, the free function is by far the preferred solution; many
people prefer it systematically, for reasons of orthogonality.

In many such cases, in fact, the free function `operator+` will be
implemented in terms of `operator+=` (which will be a member):

```
Complex
operator+( Complex const& lhs, Complex const& rhs )
{
    Complex results( lhs );
    results += rhs;
    return results;
}
```

In fact, it's fairly straightforward to provide a template base class
which provides all of these operators automatically.  (In this case,
they're declared `friend`, in order to define them in line in the
template base class.)

Answer (score 1):

Bjarne Stroustrup suggests you use the second form, for cases where you don't modify object itself or when you produce new value/object based on the provided arguments.

Comment: Interesting. I thought it wasn't a matter of preference, but simply of necessity. For instance when you want to implement `+=` or `scalar+class`, you have to use one form or the other.